# Untarring file fails when fd is not previously closed 

Tags: c, linux, file, tar, file-descriptor

Consider the following scenario: I am opening a tar file (say abc.tar.gz), writing the data, and *before* closing the file descriptor, I am trying to extract the same file.

I am unable to do so. But if I extract the file after having closing the fd, it works fine.
I wonder what could be the reason.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to untar it, and how is "[it] not allowing [you]"?

Comment: haha! I mean, the system itself, is not allowing me OR is not able to extract the file :)

Using a system call, 
system("tar -xzvf abc.tar.gz");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files has a *position* where data is read or written. After writing to the file, the position is at the end. Trying to read will attempt to read from that position. You have to change the position to the beginning of the file with a function like [`lseek`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek).

Also, you did open the file in both read and write mode?

### Edit

After reading your comments, I see you do not actually read the file from inside your program, but from an external program. Then it might be as simple as you not flushing the file to disk, which happens automatically when closing a file. You might want to check the [`fsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) function for that, or possible the [`sync`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) function.

Comment: Thanks! Just one clarification,
I'm extracting the file using a system call (system("tar -xzvf abc.tar.gz");) without closing the fd of the file. So will this system call assigns a new fd to the same file and start reading it ?

Comment: @mujahid Yes, the `system` function creates a completely new process with its own file descriptors.

Comment: But then it should read the file from the beginning. or, is it like, when you close the fd, only then, system will automatically move the position to the beginning(otherwise lseek). So, when some other process will open the file, it start reading from the beginning itself.

Comment: @mujahid I think I know what you are doing, and what the problem is. Updated my answer.